# tcpdump returns packets dropped by interface

Tags: linux, centos, tcpdump

I am trying to capture packet coming from a switch (mirror data).
but no packet is capturing.
showing all packet is dropped by interface.

```
[root@localhost PacketReceiver]# tcpdump -i enp3s0f0 -vvv -w test.pcap
tcpdump: listening on enp3s0f0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

^C0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter

0 packets dropped by kernel

162856 packets dropped by interface
```

but from another interface which by which server is using internet, by tcpdump packets are capturing fine.

What is the problem. and what will be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
ethtool -g eth0
Ring parameters for eth0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             4096
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:             256
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             256


[~] # ethtool -G eth0 rx 4096
[~] #
[~] # ethtool -g eth0
Ring parameters for eth0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             4096
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:             4096
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             256
```

This solved my issue. :)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more your solution and why it works?